# How to assert if file does not exist in Pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

I know how to assert if a file does exist, but not sure what the best way to do it is if it doesn't exist. I'm using pytest.

I have this so far, but this asserts if file does exist. I thought maybe using `!` or `not` but not sure what the standard way to do it is. Bit of a noob. Thanks!

```
    path = os.path.join("cs.log")
    assert not path.is_file()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-do-i-check-whether-a-file-exists-without-exceptions

Comment: hmm but what's the `not` of that? i.e. does not exist? and how do I assert that?

Comment: The link you supplied only shows how to check a file exists, not if a file doesn't exist.

Comment: And neither how to assert it either.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
if not os.path.exists("cs.log"):
    #stuff
    pass
```

Or, using `assert`:

```
assert os.path.exists("cs.log") == False
```

Comment: would that assert though? I want it to assert as it's a unit test

Comment: See my edit for assert. Not sure that would make any diff anyway

Comment: Thanks :) I'll try the latter even if it wouldn't make a difference :)